# Ubuntu saves the state across reboots

Tags: 16.04

My computer "saves" some status it had in a precise moment time ago. And by that I mean that everytime I turn it on, it opens the terminal windows that were open, even with the path it was, and the applications that were running. I recall installing an application that allowed me to run Thunderbird at startup, but it didn't work, and *I believe* this problem started since then. Sadly I don't remember the name of this application. Anyone know how to avoid this problem? It slows down the startup.

EDIT: I use xubuntu

Comment: what flavour of Ubuntu are you using, kubuntu usually does that...?

Comment: I use xubuntu, just added an edit.